# Computing mahalanobis distance by group using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a following sample data (d1 and d2) and am trying to compute the `mahalanobis.distance` by a variable carb and then append to the d1.

```
library(data.table)
library(StatMatch) #mahalanobis.distance

df<-as.data.table(mtcars)[carb %in% c(2,4), .(mpg, carb, vs)] # two groups of carb
d1<-df[vs==0,.(mpg,carb)]
d2<-df[vs==1,.(mpg,carb)]

#for carb==2, 

md2<-mahalanobis.dist(d1[carb==2,mpg],d2[carb==2,mpg])

             1        2        3         4         5
1 1.0416378 1.626417 1.681240 0.9502661 0.2923896
2 0.7492482 1.334027 1.388850 0.6578765 0.5847791
3 2.1380986 2.722878 2.777701 2.0467269 0.8040713
4 2.1380986 2.722878 2.777701 2.0467269 0.8040713
5 0.4934074 1.078186 1.133010 0.4020356 0.8406200
```

The dimension of matrix md2: row is row of df1 and column is row of df2.

```
#for carb==4

 md4<-mahalanobis.dist(d1[carb==4,mpg],d2[carb==4,mpg])
              1         2
    1 0.4602308 0.8181881
    2 0.4602308 0.8181881
    3 1.2528505 0.8948932
    4 2.2500173 1.8920600
    5 2.2500173 1.8920600
    6 1.1505770 0.7926197
    7 1.5085343 1.1505770
    8 0.8693248 0.5113676
```

I wonder whether it is possible to compute this using data.table by carb and then append to d1. My approach is not giving the right answer as you can see below

```
d1[,mahalanobis.dist(d1[,mpg,by=carb],d2[,mpg,by=carb]),by=carb]

     carb        V1
  1:    2 0.5925119
  2:    2 0.3136828
  3:    2 0.3136828
  4:    2 0.5576583
  5:    2 1.6381213
 ---               
178:    4 0.5925119
179:    4 0.3485364
180:    4 2.5443160
181:    4 2.5443160
182:    4 0.9759020
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm pazzeled on what exactly your desired output. Also, you don't need `with = FALSE` here at all..

Comment: @ David: Thanks for the suggestion. The desired output is the output that I computed individually for each category of carb. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need separate data sets. Just compute the distance by condition within your original data set

```
df[, mahalanobis.dist(mpg[vs == 0], mpg[vs == 1]), keyby = carb]
#    carb        V1
# 1:    2 1.0416378
# 2:    2 1.6264169
# 3:    2 1.6812399
# 4:    2 0.9502661
# 5:    2 0.2923896
# 6:    2 0.7492482
# 7:    2 1.3340273
# 8:    2 1.3888504
# 9:    2 0.6578765
# ...
```

Actually, you can run this directly on `mtcars` without creating any new data sets, for example

```
as.data.table(mtcars)[carb %in% c(2, 4), 
                      mahalanobis.dist(mpg[vs == 0], mpg[vs == 1]), 
                      keyby = carb]
```